# Creating A Multiprocessing Pool Takes Different Times

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
from time import time

def do_something(arg):
    # do something here
  
def main():
    t1 = time()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    t2 = time()
    
    # Launch async processes to do something
    futures = pool.starmap_async(do_something, [a, b])
    
    # do some other task
    
    # Wait for processes to join
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        main()
```

The function main() is run multiple times to do some task and spawns 2 processes to do some other task in parallel, while the main() function performs its own task.
However, over different runs the time (t2 - t1) is sometimes in the order of ~20 ms and other times it is approximately ~3-4s. I want to understand any possible reasons this could be happening.

I have gone through the documentation, but couldn't find a good reason. My system is a 12-core system and I have made sure that the system occupancy is low (I have tried running this piece of code after a reboot). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is `# do something here` ? your need to provide your full code that people can copy-paste and run to see your problem and tell you why that is happening.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're timing just `mp.Pool(processes=2)`.  But in any case.  On my MacOS running Python 12, the first iteration takes  13ms and the rest take 3ms.  What OS are you on? Which Python version?

Comment: @FrankYellin I timed it because I found a discrepancy in my total time and broke down the time taken by different sections. This is where the I noticed the peculiar behaviour. Adding a few times I observed for the timed section in the aforementioned code
`[0.030, 3.024, 0.043, 0.024, 3.026, 0.025, 0.026]`
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10

Comment: @AhmedAEK I am using the function to write the key-value pairs of dictionary `arg`  to a Redis server.

Comment: As an experiment, try adding `multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` immediately after the `if __name__ == "__main__"`.  Python is slowly deprecating the use of 'fork', but it is still the default on Linux. Maybe this'll help.